# How to avoid using Sorbet's T.must when the code flow already knows that value is not nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorbet

I'm using Sorbet on a Rails project and I have a method that does a calculation on a nilable property.

```rb
def age
  return unless dob && dob.year > 1900

  now = Time.now.utc.to_date
  now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
end
```

On that code, `dob` is nilable. If I run a type check on it I get a bunch of complains asking to wrap `dob` inside `T.must(dob)`:

```
app/models/person.rb:18: Method year does not exist on NilClass component of T.nilable(Date) https://srb.help/7003
    18 |    return unless dob && dob.year > 1900
                                     ^^^^
  Got T.nilable(Date) originating from:
    app/models/person.rb:18:
    18 |    return unless dob && dob.year > 1900
                                 ^^^
  Autocorrect: Use `-a` to autocorrect
    app/models/person.rb:18: Replace with T.must(dob)
    18 |    return unless dob && dob.year > 1900
                                 ^^^

app/models/person.rb:21: Method year does not exist on NilClass component of T.nilable(Date) https://srb.help/7003
    21 |    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
                           ^^^^
  Got T.nilable(Date) originating from:
    app/models/person.rb:21:
    21 |    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
                       ^^^
  Autocorrect: Use `-a` to autocorrect
    app/models/person.rb:21: Replace with T.must(dob)
    21 |    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
                       ^^^

app/models/person.rb:21: Method month does not exist on NilClass component of T.nilable(Date) https://srb.help/7003
    21 |    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
                                                    ^^^^^
  Got T.nilable(Date) originating from:
    app/models/person.rb:21:
    21 |    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
                                                ^^^
  Autocorrect: Use `-a` to autocorrect
    app/models/person.rb:21: Replace with T.must(dob)
    21 |    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
                                                ^^^

app/models/person.rb:21: Method month does not exist on NilClass component of T.nilable(Date) https://srb.help/7003
    21 |    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
                                                                               ^^^^^
  Got T.nilable(Date) originating from:
    app/models/person.rb:21:
    21 |    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
                                                                           ^^^
  Autocorrect: Use `-a` to autocorrect
    app/models/person.rb:21: Replace with T.must(dob)
    21 |    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
                                                                           ^^^

app/models/person.rb:21: Method day does not exist on NilClass component of T.nilable(Date) https://srb.help/7003
    21 |    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
                                                                                                       ^^^
  Got T.nilable(Date) originating from:
    app/models/person.rb:21:
    21 |    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
                                                                                                   ^^^
  Autocorrect: Use `-a` to autocorrect
    app/models/person.rb:21: Replace with T.must(dob)
    21 |    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
```

What is the best way to tell Sorbet that `dob` won't be nil since I'm already returning if it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Sorbet's most-commonly asked question, and it appears at the top of the [Sorbet FAQ page](https://sorbet.org/docs/faq).

The short answer is that you need to assign `dob` to a variable (despite not having any parentheses, `dob` is in fact a call to a method in this context, because there has not been an assignment to a variable called `dob` in this scope).

In your case, the easiest fix is to write `dob = self.dob` at the top of the method, which calls the `dob` method once and assigns it to a variable:

```rb
def age
  dob = self.dob
  return unless dob && dob.year > 1900

  now = Time.now.utc.to_date
  now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
end
```

[→ View full example on sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aclass%20DOB%20%3C%20T%3A%3AStruct%0A%20%20prop%20%3Ayear%2C%20Integer%0A%20%20prop%20%3Amonth%2C%20Integer%0A%20%20prop%20%3Aday%2C%20Integer%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Breturns%28T.nilable%28DOB%29%29%7D%0A%20%20def%20dob%3B%20end%0A%0A%20%20def%20age%0A%20%20%20%20dob%20%3D%20self.dob%0A%20%20%20%20return%20unless%20dob%20%26%26%20dob.year%20%3E%201900%0A%0A%20%20%20%20now%20%3D%20Time.now.utc.to_date%0A%20%20%20%20now.year%20-%20dob.year%20-%20%28%28now.month%20%3E%20dob.month%20%7C%7C%20%28now.month%20%3D%3D%20dob.month%20%26%26%20now.day%20%3E%3D%20dob.day%29%29%20%3F%200%20%3A%201%29%0A%20%20end%0Aend)

All references of `dob` after the first assignment are now reads from the local variable, instead of calls to the method, which allows Sorbet to remember any flow-sensitive type analyses it has performed.